# jackson failing to map empty array with No content to map to Object due to end of input

Tags: java, json, jackson

I send a query to an api and map the json results to my classes using Jackson.
When I get some results it works fine, but when there are no results it fails with

```
java.io.EOFException: No content to map to Object due to end of input
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:2766)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2709)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1854)
at com.jthink.discogs.query.DiscogsServerQuery.mapQuery(DiscogsServerQuery.java:382)
at com.jthink.discogs.query.SearchQuery.mapQuery(SearchQuery.java:37)*
```

But the thing is the api isn't returning nothing at all, so I dont see why it is failing.

Here is the query:

```
http://api.discogs.com/database/search?page=1&type=release&release_title=nude+and+rude+the+best+of+iggy+pop
```

this is what I get back

```
{
    "pagination": {
        "per_page": 50,
        "pages": 1,
        "page": 1,
        "urls": {},
        "items": 0
    },
    "results": []
}
```

and here is the top level object Im trying to map to

```
public class Search
{
    private Pagination pagination;
    private Result[] results;

    public Pagination getPagination() {
        return pagination;
    }

    public void setPagination(Pagination pagination) {
        this.pagination = pagination;
    }

    public Result[] getResults() {
        return results;
    }

    public void setResults(Result[] results) {
        this.results = results;
    }
}
```

Im guessing the problem is something to do with the results array being returned being blank, but cant see what Im doing wrong

EDIT:
The comment below was correct, although I usually receive

```
{
    "pagination": {
        "per_page": 50,
        "pages": 1,
        "page": 1,
        "urls": {},
        "items": 0
    },
    "results": []
}
```

and in these cases there is no problem but sometimes I seem to just get an empty String. Now Im wondering if the problem is how I read from the inputstream

```
 if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
        InputStreamReader in= new InputStreamReader(uc.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader    br= new BufferedReader(in);
        while(br.ready())
        {
            String next = br.readLine();
            sb.append(next);
        }
        return sb.toString();
  }
```

although I dont read until I get the response code, is it possible that the first time I call br.ready() that I call it before it is ready, and therefore I don't read the input

EDIT 2:

Changing above code to simply

```
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            sb.append(line);
        }
```

resolved the issue.

Comment: I doubt Jackson would behave this way if the stream infact has data. I would suggest read the stream and print the data out to console where you are doing jackson deserialization to make sure there infact is data to be read at that point.

Comment: Yes, you are correct I'm not always providing jackson with the data I thought I was, I've updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing above code to simply

```
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            sb.append(line);
        }
```

resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Although there is one solution already, I would suggest alternative where you first create `JsonParser` and then see if there is any input, and if so, use data bind. This is much faster than reading input line by line, constructing a String, and then handing it to parser.

```
JsonParser jp = jsonFactory.createJsonParser(uc.getInputStream());
Search result = null;
if (jp.nextToken() != null) { // end-of-input
  result = jp.readValueAs(Search.class);
}
jp.close();
return result;
```

Comment: I'm currently using ObjectMapper.readValue() which can actually take an input stream so I'm guessing changing it to take the inputstream directly would have the same effect ?

Comment: Yes. You only need to use parser if you need to read multiple separate values or such.